# Solve : $ x(4ydx+2xdy)+y^3(3ydx+5xdy)=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve:

$ x(4ydx+2xdy)+y^3(3ydx+5xdy)=0 $

See Q.26 in the handwritten solution. The correct answer is: 
$$ x^4y^2 + x^3y^5 = c $$ What I may have done wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a mistake last picture first line . You cant integrate $$\int 3\frac {y^3}{x^2}dx$$ As you did because you have both $y,x$ in the integral

Comment: @Isham   Yes, but in case of exact equations, y is considered a constant.

Comment: No you can't do that. It will give you the wrong answer. You have a dx so the function must be only a function of x.

Comment: I was told that the solution to exact differential equation is $ \int Mdx (y-considered-costant) dx + \int (Terms_--of-N-not-containing-xdy) = C $

Comment: Soumee we both have the same integrating factor. $\mu(x,y)=x^2y$ But you divided the equation by it when I muliplied the equation instead. Can you check that ?

Comment: @Isham  Oh! yes. You are right. Have a nice day ahead :)

Comment: You are welcome. Not that the answer provided has $y^3$ it should be if I am not mistaken $y^5$. Have a nice day too Soumee.

Comment: @Isham Your answer is correct. I have mistakenly typed the power as 3

Comment: Ok thank you. Do the calculation again with integrating factor it should work fine. You have the right integrating factor.

Comment: @Isham Yes I'll do it as you told. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am checking your answer to find the mistakes if there are ones. Here is my approach.
$$x(4ydx+2xdy)+y^3(3ydx+5xdy)=0$$
$$2(2yxdx+x^2dy)+y^3(3ydx+5xdy)=0$$
$$2(dx^2y)+y^3(3ydx+5xdy)=0$$
multiply by $\mu(x,y)=x^2y$
$$2x^2y(dx^2y)+x^2y^4(3ydx+5xdy)=0$$
$$2x^2y(dx^2y)+(3x^2y^5dx+5x^3y^4dy)=0$$
$$2x^2y(dx^2y)+d(x^3y^5)=0$$
integrate:
$$x^4y^2+x^3y^5=K$$
Are you sure it's exponent three in the answer ? And not five ?